# _api/search/query?querytext='Office:Chicago' yildes no results

Tags: rest, search, sharepoint

I have a PROD and DEV farms using the same AD domain.
A query using _api/search/query?querytext='Office:Chicago'&sourceid='b09a7990-05ea-4af9-81ef-edfab16c4e31' 
Brings Lots of results from the PROD farm but nothing from the DEV farm and no errors are showing. search on the UI of DEV does find people. but not using 'Office:Chicago'.

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `sourceid` parameter? I imagine those are not equivalent between both farms.

Comment: The SouceID for people search is the same GUID for all SharePoint farms.

Comment: When's the last time you did a full crawl on the dev farm?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you can get results using **the query** in the UI first.  Since you can't get results, make sure of some things:

1. The column's indexed managed property name is correct and the mapping exists
2. Enough time has passed to be indexed
3. Do a full index if its been recently added
4. Items with the tagging exist, and have been crawled

Here are names for OOTB properties: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219630.aspx